# can we pass pipeline variable inside the for each loop or other iterative activities

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am using azure data factory to download a file using the copy activity. The copy activity is called inside the `for each` activity. I need to pass a variable that can be used in the copy activity .

But I get an error saying `"The output of variable <variable name> can't be referenced since it is not a variable of the current pipeline"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use [Set Variable Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-set-variable-activity) with Copy Activity in the ForEach Activity.

Set Variable Activity:

> Use the Set Variable activity to set the value of an existing variable
>   of type String, Bool, or Array defined in a Data Factory pipeline.

[image]

Then you could use it with dynamic content,such as `@activity('Set Variable1').value`

Comment: @vikaskumar Great!Please mark the answer to end this case. Thank you!

Comment: As I am new to this, not sure how to mark this as the answer. If you could help

Comment: @vikaskumar Sure,maybe you could see a hook near my answer,then you could mark it.Also,you could vote up it if you click the arrow.

Answer (score 1):

Before you can use a variable, you must first declare it in the scopt of the pipeline.

1. Go to pipeline view
2. Click in empty whitespace, so you are not focused on any activity
3. Select the Variable tab
4. Make you variable

Please be aware that when setting the value of a variable, it cannot reference itself (X=X+1).  I.E. You cannot use a variable as a counter during a for-each loop.
[Pipeline variable declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri3RM.png)